# idioms for returning multiple values in shell scripting

Tags: shell, idioms

Are there any idioms for returning multiple values from a bash function within a script?

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/assortedtips.html describes how to echo multiple values and process the results (e.g., example 35-17), but that gets tricky if some of the returned values are strings with spaces in.

A more structured way to return would be to assign to global variables, like

```
foo () {
    FOO_RV1="bob"
    FOO_RV2="bill"
}

foo
echo "foo returned ${FOO_RV1} and ${FOO_RV2}"
```

I realize that if I need re-entrancy in a shell script I'm probably doing it wrong, but I still feel very uncomfortable throwing global variables around just to hold return values.

Is there a better way? I would prefer portability, but it's probably not a real limitation if I have to specify `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: New answer: `declare -n`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76127851/633961

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Much as I love shell, it's probably the case that as soon as you're throwing arbitrary structured data around, Unix bourne/posix shell is not the right choice.

If there are characters which do not occur inside fields, then separate with one of those.  The classic example is `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` and various other files which use a colon as a field separator.

If using a shell which can handle a NUL character inside strings, then joining on the NUL and separating on it (via $IFS or whatever) can work well.  But several common shells, including bash, break on NUL.  A test would be an old .sig of mine:

```
foo=$'a\0b'; [ ${#foo} -eq 3 ] && echo "$0 rocks"
```

Even if that would work for you, you've just reached one of the warning signs that it's time to switch to a more structured language (Python, Perl, Ruby, Lua, Javascript ... pick your preferred poison).  Your code is likely to become hard to maintain; even if you can, there's  a smaller pool of people who'll understand it well enough to maintain it.

Answer (score 36):

In the special case where **your values never contain spaces**, this `read` trick can be a simple solution:

```
get_vars () {
  #...
  echo "value1" "value2"
}

read var1 var2 < <(get_vars)
echo "var1='$var1', var2='$var2'"
```

But of course, it breaks as soon as there is a space in one of the values. You could modify `IFS` and use a special separator in your function's `echo`, but then the result is not really simpler than the other suggested solutions.

Comment: Just a note when used with "\n" delimiter, `read` may return exit code `1`, even if it has actually succeeded, except for not finding the line terminator. [See](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80045/read-a-array-d-n-foo-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 30):

This question was posted 5 years ago, but I have some interesting answer to post. I have just started learning bash, and I also encounter to the same problem as you did. I think this trick might be helpful:

```
#!/bin/sh

foo=""
bar=""

my_func(){
    echo 'foo="a"; bar="b"'
}

eval $(my_func)
echo $foo $bar
# result: a b
```

This trick is also useful for solving a problem when a child process can not send back a value to its parent process.

Comment: Although it's not perfect, I like it generally applicable.

Comment: How to set varibale for foo?

Answer (score 3):

Later version of Bash supports *nameref*. Use `declare -n var_name` to give `var_name` the *nameref* attribute. *nameref* gives your function the ability to "pass by reference" which is commonly used in C++ functions to return multiple values. According to Bash man page:

> A variable can be assigned the *nameref* attribute using the **-n** option to the **declare** or **local** builtin commands to create a *nameref*, or a reference to another variable. This allows variables to  be manipulated indirectly. Whenever the *nameref* variable is referenced or assigned to, the operation is actually performed on the variable specified by the *nameref* variable's value.  A *nameref* is commonly used within shell functions to refer to a variable whose name is passed as an argument to the function.

The following are some interactive command line examples.

**Example 1:**

```
$ unset xx yy
$ xx=16
$ yy=xx
$ echo "[$xx] [$yy]"
[16] [xx]
$ declare -n yy
$ echo "[$xx] [$yy]"
[16] [16]
$ xx=80
$ echo "[$xx] [$yy]"
[80] [80]
$ yy=2016
$ echo "[$xx] [$yy]"
[2016] [2016]
$ declare +n yy # Use -n to add and +n to remove nameref attribute.
$ echo "[$xx] [$yy]"
[2016] [xx]
```

**Example 2:**

```
$ func()
> {
>     local arg1="$1" arg2="$2"
>     local -n arg3ref="$3" arg4ref="$4"
> 
>     echo ''
>     echo 'Local variables:'
>     echo "    arg1='$arg1'"
>     echo "    arg2='$arg2'"
>     echo "    arg3ref='$arg3ref'"
>     echo "    arg4ref='$arg4ref'"
>     echo ''
> 
>     arg1='1st value of local assignment'
>     arg2='2st value of local assignment'
>     arg3ref='1st return value'
>     arg4ref='2nd return value'
> }
$ 
$ unset foo bar baz qux
$ 
$ foo='value of foo'
$ bar='value of bar'
$ baz='value of baz'
$ qux='value of qux'
$ 
$ func foo bar baz qux

Local variables:
    arg1='foo'
    arg2='bar'
    arg3ref='value of baz'
    arg4ref='value of qux'

$ 
$ {
>     echo ''
>     echo '2 values are returned after the function call:'
>     echo "    foo='$foo'"
>     echo "    bar='$bar'"
>     echo "    baz='$baz'"
>     echo "    qux='$qux'"
> }

2 values are returned after the function call:
    foo='value of foo'
    bar='value of bar'
    baz='1st return value'
    qux='2nd return value'
```

Answer (score 3):

In order version of Bash which doesn't support *nameref* (introduced in Bash 4.3-alpha) I may define helper function in which the return value is assigned to the given variable. It's sort of like using `eval` to do the same kind of variable assignment.

**Example 1**

```
##  Add two complex numbers and returns it.
##  re: real part, im: imaginary part.
##
##  Helper function named by the 5th positional parameter
##  have to have been defined before the function is called.
complexAdd()
{
    local re1="$1" im1="$2" re2="$3" im2="$4" fnName="$5" sumRe sumIm

    sumRe=$(($re1 + $re2))
    sumIm=$(($im1 + $im2))

    ##  Call the function and return 2 values.
    "$fnName" "$sumRe" "$sumIm"
}

main()
{
    local fooRe='101' fooIm='37' barRe='55' barIm='123' bazRe bazIm quxRe quxIm

    ##  Define the function to receive mutiple return values
    ##  before calling complexAdd().
    retValAssign() { bazRe="$1"; bazIm="$2"; }
    ##  Call comlexAdd() for the first time.
    complexAdd "$fooRe" "$fooIm" "$barRe" "$barIm" 'retValAssign'

    ##  Redefine the function to receive mutiple return values.
    retValAssign() { quxRe="$1"; quxIm="$2"; }
    ##  Call comlexAdd() for the second time.
    complexAdd "$barRe" "$barIm" "$bazRe" "$bazIm" 'retValAssign'

    echo "foo = $fooRe + $fooIm i"
    echo "bar = $barRe + $barIm i"
    echo "baz = foo + bar = $bazRe + $bazIm i"
    echo "qux = bar + baz = $quxRe + $quxIm i"
}

main
```

**Example 2**

```
##  Add two complex numbers and returns it.
##  re: real part, im: imaginary part.
##
##  Helper functions
##      getRetRe(), getRetIm(), setRetRe() and setRetIm()
##  have to have been defined before the function is called.
complexAdd()
{
    local re1="$1" im1="$2" re2="$3" im2="$4"

    setRetRe "$re1"
    setRetRe $(($(getRetRe) + $re2))

    setRetIm $(($im1 + $im2))
}

main()
{
    local fooRe='101' fooIm='37' barRe='55' barIm='123' bazRe bazIm quxRe quxIm

    ##  Define getter and setter functions before calling complexAdd().
    getRetRe() { echo "$bazRe"; }
    getRetIm() { echo "$bazIm"; }
    setRetRe() { bazRe="$1"; }
    setRetIm() { bazIm="$1"; }
    ##  Call comlexAdd() for the first time.
    complexAdd "$fooRe" "$fooIm" "$barRe" "$barIm"

    ##  Redefine getter and setter functions.
    getRetRe() { echo "$quxRe"; }
    getRetIm() { echo "$quxIm"; }
    setRetRe() { quxRe="$1"; }
    setRetIm() { quxIm="$1"; }
    ##  Call comlexAdd() for the second time.
    complexAdd "$barRe" "$barIm" "$bazRe" "$bazIm"

    echo "foo = $fooRe + $fooIm i"
    echo "bar = $barRe + $barIm i"
    echo "baz = foo + bar = $bazRe + $bazIm i"
    echo "qux = bar + baz = $quxRe + $quxIm i"
}

main
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

```
function get_tuple()
{
  echo -e "Value1\nValue2"
}

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra VALUES < <(get_tuple)
echo "${VALUES[0]}" # Value1
echo "${VALUES[1]}" # Value2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of associative arrays with you have bash 4 eg

```
declare -A ARR
function foo(){
  ...
  ARR["foo_return_value_1"]="VAR1"
  ARR["foo_return_value_2"]="VAR2"
}
```

you can combine them as strings.

```
function foo(){
  ...
  echo "$var1|$var2|$var3"
}
```

then whenever you need to use those return values,

```
ret="$(foo)"
IFS="|"
set -- $ret
echo "var1 one is: $1"
echo "var2 one is: $2"
echo "var3 one is: $3"
```

Comment: Just yesterday I have read a comment from another user, relating to a similar answer to another question. She pointed out that things like `set -- $ret` are dangerous, because `$ret` undergoes filename expansion / pattern matching in constructs like this, at least in bash (I don't know other shells). If `$ret` happens to contain the respective wildcard characters, and if there are matching paths or filenames, this could lead to wrong results and very nasty and hard-to-find problems.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the solution I [suggested here](/a/14541533/332820), but using an array variable instead. Older bash:es don't support associative arrays.
E.g.,

```
function some_func() # ARRVAR args...
{
    local _retvar=$1 # I use underscore to avoid clashes with return variable names
    local -a _out
    # ... some processing ... (_out[2]=xxx etc.)
    eval $_retvar='("${_out[@]}")'
}
```

Calling site:

```
function caller()
{
    local -a tuple_ret # Do not use leading '_' here.
    # ...
    some_func tuple_ret "arg1"
    printf "  %s\n" "${tuple_ret[@]}" # Print tuple members on separate lines
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new to bash, But found this code helping.

```
function return_multiple_values() {
        eval "$1='What is your name'"
        eval "$2='my name is: BASH'"
    }
    
    return_var=''
    res2=''
    return_multiple_values return_var res2
    echo $return_var
    echo $res2
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell script functions can only return the exit status of last command executed or the exit status of that function specified explicitly by a return statement.

To return some string one way may be this:

```
function fun()
{
  echo "a+b"
}

var=`fun` # Invoke the function in a new child shell and capture the results
echo $var # use the stored result
```

This may reduce your discomfort although it adds the overhead of creation of a new shell and hence would be marginally slower.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick (when awk is available and read is not in the system):

```
#!/bin/sh

get_vars() {
    echo "value1 value2"
}

main() {
    local vars="$(get_vars)"
    local var1="$(echo ${vars} | awk '{print $1}')"
    local var2="$(echo ${vars} | awk '{print $2}')"

    echo "var1='$var1', var2='$var2'"
}

main
```

Output:

```
var1='value1', var2='value2'
```