# return two values from perl to bash variables

Tags: perl, bash, return, exit

I am calling a perl script to calculate size and variation in bash script. Is there a way to return those two values to separated variables in bash, say $SIZE and $VAR. Only know how to return one value.

Comment: You can find some inspiration in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488715/idioms-for-returning-multiple-values-in-shell-scripting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of returning (which is mainly used for an error/success code from the script), you can print your variables from the perl script, separated by, say, space, and then read them from bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$size=1;
$var=2;
print "$size $var\n";
```

and:

```
#!/bin/bash
read SIZE VAR <<<$(my_perl_script)
echo size: $SIZE var: $VAR
```

Comment: I might use `read SIZE VAR < <( my_perl_script )` instead (but only because it is very slightly cleaner looking).

Comment: @chepner: I prefer `<<<` to `< <(` because it doesn't create a named pipe. In most cases, the performance hit won't make any difference though.

Comment: @MkV: The question specifically asked for a _bash script_. Why not take advantage of the bash features then?

Answer (score 1):

you can only do that by evaluating perl's output e.g.:

from perl:

```
print "SIZE=1 VAR=blah"
```

then in shell script:

```
export `your perl script.pl`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set -- $(perl yourscript)

size=$1
var=$2
```