# Returning multiple values from shell script to c program

Tags: c, shell, struct, return-value

I am calling a shell script from a c program. I want this script to return multiple values which I want to store in a structure of my c program. For instance say 'a.c' calls 'a.sh', I want 'a.sh' to return the values to be stored in variables 'x' and 'y' which are a part of struct 's' in 'a.c'.

Comment: And you've tried what ?

Comment: I have no clue as to what to do!

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488715/idioms-for-returning-multiple-values-in-shell-scripting) Good discussions has already taken place on these topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "return" values from a shell script, other than the single integer (often limited to 8 bits) of exit status that processes have (assuming a Unix-like system, now).

What you typically do is interpret the *standard output* of the external program, which you can easily read into your C program by using [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to run the shell script.

You can transfer any amount of data using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution (but very quick and easy to implement) but you could always produce an output file from the shell script and then parse that file from the C program. This has the benefit that you can store the output values of the shell script between executions of your C program, useful if those output values do not change every time.