# Returning multiple arguments from Bash function

Tags: bash

I know that you use a `echo "return-value"` and `$(my_function)` to call functions in the bash.

But maybe there is an extension to bash, so that you can return two values?

It would be really great, if I could use this pattern (like in Go):

```
function my_function()
    ....
    return "foo", 0
```

Usage of the function:

```
value, err = my_function()
```

Comment: You could `echo` those values with a delimiter and 'split' then after calling the function. Or just globals.

Comment: You can use multiple file descriptors, but you'll find this bothersome if you wan't to avoid using files or calling the function multiple times.  Here's an example : https://ideone.com/logDyP

Comment: Functions in bash don't have a return value. Actually, the word _function_ is a misnomer and they should have better be called _subroutines_. The `return` statement just sets an exit code which the caller can pick up using the variable `$?`. Since you should reasonably only use values from 0 to 126 for an exit code, this mechanism is at best suitable for communicating back very small non-negative integers.

Comment: Instead you use some differenct mechanism for passing information from a function to the caller: Write the data to a file which is then read by the caller, write data to stdout and/or stderr, use global shell variables, use namerefs, just to give some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With recent bash you can use namerefs and pass your function the names of the variables to assign: `my_function value err`. Example:

```
$ my_function() {
  local -n v="$1" e="$2"
  v="foo bar"
  e="baz qux"
}
$ my_function value err
$ echo "$value"
foo bar
$ echo "$err"
baz qux
```

You can also design your function to print two string values on the standard output separated by a custom separator that cannot be found in the string values (for instance a newline) and assign this to an array:

```
$ my_function() {
  local v e
  v="foo bar"
  e="baz qux"
  printf '%s\n%s' "$v" "$e"
}
$ IFS=$'\n' arr=($(my_function))
$ echo "${arr[0]}"
foo bar
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
baz qux
```

And again with namerefs you can have kind of named aliases for the array elements:

```
$ declare -n value=arr[0] err=arr[1]
$ echo "$value"
foo bar
$ echo "$err"
baz qux
```

Comment: Great! But I struggle to find the official docs about this great feature.

Comment: Just type `man bash` and read the `PARAMETERS` section. Or visit [the bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) and search `nameref`.